# Generating raster from isolines using SAGA or ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, saga, contour

I have a vector dataset of mean annual precipitation polylines, and I would like to generate a raster from them. I'm not sure the best way to go about it.

ArcGIS has the **Polyline to Raster** tool but from reading its help file I get the impression it's not really designed to do what I need it to do. Obviously some kind of interpolation is required.

I am hoping that SAGA-GIS might have a useful module. Either that or I guess I could convert the lines to points and then krige them.

Comment: Wondering if there is an approach in R that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 4):

Giving you GRASS and GDAL based answer if that's an option for you.

GRASS - r.surf.contour is the tool meant to interpolate contours to create DEM. http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM#r.surf.contour

If using GDAL is an option, try this. ( Install OSGeo4W and run following from shell ). This is an easier option, but kind of a hack, so use with care.

Assuming your isolines layer is called isoline.shp and your polylines have an attribute named PRECIPITATION

Convert to raster , X is the resolution of the output raster

gdal_rasterize -a PRECIPITATION isoline.shp iso_raster.tif -tr X X

Fill intermediate values by interpolation, change XX to appropriate value.

gdal_fillnodata.py -md XX iso_raster.tif iso_raster_interpolated.tif -mask iso_raster.tif

Comment: You called this a 'hack' . What is the problem with this? Is the final output not correct?

Comment: I used that term because gdal_fillnodata.py wasn't designed for this purpose. I believe the output would be correct but you need to choose the correct value of the -md based on trial and error.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Spatial Analyst extension you could try the **Topo to Raster** tool.  This tool is primarily used for converting existing elevation contours to a hydrologically correct DEM but it could work fine for your purpose since it bascally uses some modified interpolation functions.

> ESRI: This method **"Topo to Raster"** uses an iterative finite difference interpolation
>   technique. It is optimized to have the computational efficiency of
>   local interpolation methods, such as inverse distance weighted (IDW)
>   interpolation, without losing the surface continuity of global
>   interpolation methods, such as Kriging and Spline. It is essentially a
>   discretized thin plate spline technique (Wahba, 1990) for which the
>   roughness penalty has been modified to allow the fitted DEM to follow
>   abrupt changes in terrain, such as streams and ridges.

Answer (score 0):

Use the topo lines to create a TIN where the TINs z values are the precip values from the contours, convert the TIN to a raster.

Comment: Than you for answering--but isn't this much already stated in the question? I believe the OP would like to know *how* to do these things.